# is it possible to fully override a property in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

i have a parent class coming from a library i don't control, and i'm trying to create a child class that overrides a public property in that class. i found that the answer is to use the `new` keyword, but i'm confused about the behavior. here is an example:

```cs
public class A {
    public string Q { get; private set; }

    public A(string q) {
        Q = q;
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public new string Q { get; private set; }
    
    public B(string q) : base("no") {
        Q = q;
    }
}
...
[Fact]
public void Test() {
    var a = new A("a");
    var b = new B("b");
    A c = new B("c");

    throw new Exception($"{a.Q} {b.Q} {c.Q}");
}
```

this results in:

```
System.Exception: a b no
```

but i want:

```
System.Exception: a b c
```

the code i'm calling accepts an `A`, so i pass it an instance of my child class `B` that has a customized property getter, but the library code is still using the getter from `A`, which results in incorrect behavior.

is this just not possible? i tried the same thing with methods instead of properties and it also didn't work. i'm so confused ;-;

Comment: An example why it is important to code against interfaces...

Comment: You can't sorry.  A solution would be to not us A directly or derive from it but write a Wrapper around A and only use that Wrapper if the changed behavior is only relevant in that domain. If you need changed behavior for A also within the 3rd Party library its defined in you are really out of luck.

Comment: Is see the Fact attribute. Is this actually for unittests? There might be Mocking Frameworks that grab deeply into the compiled code and do "bad" things to make it work. Nothing you want in production code but might be ok in a test.

Comment: You could use reflection to access the private property-setter in your constructor of `B`. However that applies to these "bad things" ralf mentioned, as it's easy to break your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the point of `new` is, that it only *hides* the overriden member. That member still exists with the exact same name, so when you're accessing your instance via a base-class *reference*, the base-class-member is called.

An easier way of thinking is, that `new` just introduces a completely new member, e.g.:

```
class A
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Now instead of *overriding* `MyString`, the `new`-keyword just creates a second property, which has no relation to `MyString` from class `A`. So what the compiler more or less does, is creating a second member (e.g. `AnotherString`) in your derived class with another name and replace all occurences of `B.MyString` in the codebase by that new property:

```
class B : A
{
    // actually this property has the same name, however it has nothing to do with MyString from class A
    public string AnotherString { get; set; } 
}
```

Now all calls to `B.MyString` are replaced by `B.AnotherString`. However your library surely has no clue `B` even exists. There will allways ever be only refereces to your base-class. So the compiler won't replace these properties. Effectivly you have two properties, not just one.

This is just a simplification, the compiler won't *really* rename your property, but it's easier to get the idea.

So when your library-provider didn't implement any means of extensibility - which is by making the member `abstract` or `virtual`, there is **no way** of extending it.

Comment: ;-; i cry. but thank you, that really clarifies what's happening and that what i want can't be done

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself using the `new` keyword in this context, it means that you are *hiding* rather than *overriding* the property. In order to use the `override` keyword, you would need to declare your property as `virtual`.

You would also need to make the property setters `protected` rather than `private` so that the derived classes can access them:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string Q { get; protected set; }

    public A(string q)
    {
        Q = q;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string Q { get; protected set; }

    public B(string q) : base("no")
    {
        Q = q;
    }
}
```

After making these changes, the output will be the desired `System.Exception: a b c`.

But since you cannot change the parent class then unfortunately the answer to your question in this case is "No, you cannot do that".

This underlines the fact that classes should be *designed* to be derived from if that's what's wanted. For this reason, some people declare as `sealed` classes that have not been so designed, to prevent people from even attempting to derive from them.

Comment: OP mentions `A` is from a 3rd party they do not control, so I guess, making `Q` virtual is off the table.

Comment: Ah in that case they are out of luck.

Comment: _"This underlines the fact that classes should be designed to be derived from"_ - and APIs to use Interfaces.

Comment: @Fildor not all classes should be designed to be derived. But in this case the intent is not clear. They either not intend people to derive and they forgot to use `sealed` or they wanted to allow and botched it

Comment: Neither me nor Matthew said _all_ classes.  @Franck I personally would be a little less strict on internal ones that I control. But public api: seal it or prepare it.

Comment: thank you! this helped explain things. if only the library i'm using used interfaces ;-;

Answer (score 1):

Just a second answer for the sake of completeness. While the above answers are conceptual correct, there are some dirty ways to achieve this - which essentially mocking-frameworks tend to use when providing fakes for static members for instance. However these highly rely on diving into the internals of the library and therefor introduce a very strong dependency on it. E.g. when the internals of that lib change, your code may break. So I strongly suggest the following disclaimer:

> **Don't do this for production-code**

You can use reflection to access any `private` member from your library. So when you know the internals, e.g. backing-field-names and such, you could use reflection to access and manipulate them. In your case you have a `private` setter, which you can use in your constructor of class `B`:

```
public B(string value)
{
    var setter = typeof(A).GetProperty("Q").GetSetMethod(true);
    setter.Invoke(this, new object[] { value });
}
```

As already mentioned: while this works, you introduce a strong coupling to the internals of class `A`. Imagine for instance the property is changed to the following, while maintaining the public interface:

```
public class A
{
    public string Q { get; } // no private setter
    public class A(string q) { this.Q = q; }
}
```

This would break your code, as the property has no private setter any more. Accessing it in the constructor throws an exception.

Comment: ohh thank you! i actually am trying to mock some objects for testing, so this is exactly what i needed! i was hoping i didn't have to use reflection, but i guess i do v_v. very much agreed about the strong coupling. i only decided to try this because the library is very seldom changed and i'm mocking pretty simple objects.